# mysql merge three different values from different rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, rows

I haven't found an answer specific enough for exactly what I'm looking for, so I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate question.

I am trying to create a list of full names in a results list that looks like this:

```
id  | form_id | element_label | element_value | group_id
245   10        1               John            34
245   10        2               A               34
245   10        3               Doe             34
245   10        1               George          35
245   10        2               C               35
245   10        3               Washington      35
```

This is from my query:
SELECT * FROM  `jm3_formmaker_submits` WHERE  `form_id` =  '10' AND  `element_label` <4

The result I want would be:

```
group_id | full_name
34         John A Doe
35         George C Washington
```

Thank you so very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look on **[`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** function.

It will be something like this:

```
SELECT group_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(element_value 
                    ORDER BY element_label
                    SEPARATOR ' ')
         AS full_name 
FROM jm3_formmaker_submits 
WHERE form_id = 10 
  AND element_label < 4 
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Comment: Thanks dull; appreciate the answer.

Comment: No need for `REPLACE()`. The [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function has `SEPARATOR`.

Answer (score 0):

This one will give you more control on string structure (I guess you will want to separate them with spaces, won't you?):

```
select group_id,concat(a,' ',b,' ',c) from
(select group_id,element_value as a from jm3_formmaker_submits where element_label=1) as first_name,
(select group_id,element_value as b from jm3_formmaker_submits where element_label=2) as middle_name,
(select group_id,element_value as c from jm3_formmaker_submits where element_label=3) as last__name
where
middle_name.group_id=first_name.group_id and
last__name.group_id=first_name.group_id
```

Comment: Better to use REPLACE() mysql function.

Comment: @drull where in particular?